# Need help solving two number puzzles

Tags: number-sequence

1st Puzzle:
Can you find the next two numbers in the sequence: 122540, 577697, ?, ?

2nd Puzzle:
Solve this sequence: 28) 123456, 777, 154, ?, ?

Both questions are from https://free.ultimaiq.net/nse.htm

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Questions should only contain one puzzle at a time; I'd suggest splitting this up into two separate posts, once per sequence.

Comment: Having only two numbers in the first means there is far too little information to solve it normally.  What is the context?  Do you interpret the numbers abnormally?  In the second, the bouncing around suggests a nonstandard interpretation..  Did you mean the parenthesis or is it a typo?

Comment: I love the instruction *"Hint: If you find more than one logical solution to a particular item, you must choose the **most logical** one."*

Comment: @RossMillikan going into the site suggests that the parenthesis are part of the 28, as it is the question 28.

Answer (score 2):

For the second, now that we know the $28)$ is just the question number I would suggest $105,6$ or $60,6$ as possible answers.  I get the $777$ from $123456$ by adding first and last digits, but I can't tell whether the first or last $7$ comes from the first and last digits.  Then to get $154$ from $777$ we again add first and last digits and twice the middle because we have an odd number of digits and add (not concatenate) the two $14$s with one offset by one place.  We then do $1+4=5$ and $5+5=10$ which we combine either as $50+10=60$ or $100+5=105$.  I left this unspoilered because I think believing any of it silly.

Comment: Yes, it is valid answer for question 28.